# Group theory: Computing the quotient of free abelian groups for homology groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, finitely-generated, quotient-group

I just started reading about the general idea behind homology theory (Hatcher). During his introduction he is computing the Homology groups $H_n(X)$ of a given space $X$ by building the quotient of the generators of $\ker \partial_n$ and $\operatorname{Im} \partial_{n+1}$.

Unfortunately, my algebra background is not too solid and therefore i don't know how exactly the quotient of two given generators is supposed to be computed.

Intuitively, i understood that $$\langle a, b, c\rangle/\langle a,b\rangle = \langle c\rangle $$ or $$(\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$$

However, that was mostly my intuitive guess and i do not know what the algebraic reasons behind the solutions are. I tried googling but haven't gotten far.

I basically just need a hint or advice what theorem/topic/chapter i need to study in order to learn the algebraic background for this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know what quotient groups and rings are?

Comment: yes. but how do i compute the generator of the quotient $G/U$ given the generators of $G$ and $U$?

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem is a basic tool: to prove $A/N\cong B$ just find a surjective homomorphism $A\to B$ whose kernel is $N$. For example, for $\langle a,b,c\rangle \to\langle c\rangle$ consider the homomorphism described by $a,b\mapsto 1,\,c\mapsto c$ (though your equation only works for Abelian groups).

Comment: Hello Berci, that's what i was looking for. Thank you very much. In fact, i am only considering free abelian groups, thus this is perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second equation need not be true.

Comment: in which scenario is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the first isomorphism theorem as mentioned by @Berci, another tool is the classification of finitely generated abelian groups. The kernel of any boundary map is a subgroup of a finitely generated free abelian group, and hence is finitely generated free abelian. Then the homology is a quotient of that, so it's a finitely generated abelian group. So you could read about this classification theorem and also Smith Normal Form. Visit https://www.williamstein.org/papers/ant/html/node9.html, for example.